# How to compile .elf files in Cygwin

Tags: unix, cygwin

I am learning Linux. I am using the Cygwin 64.  I know Cygwin 64 terminal compiles output files in Windows PE format(when normally Linux automatically compiles output in .elf format), but I would like to use readelf to a program. So how do I compile my code using Cygwin 64 so it compiles the output in .elf format? Thanks.